# BSVue and VuejS2: How to show correct toggle state of accordion icons?

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap-Vue's accordion component and I am struggling with trying to figure out how I can show the correct collapse state for the `+` and `-` icons on the right hand side of the accordion buttons.

Does anyone know how to start the icon in the `+` state and when the user clicks the accordion button and shows the content, I want the icon to be `-`.

[image]

I hope this makes sense. I have JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/26gvdxqo/

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the code will fix your issue:

```
...

<div class="when-open"> + </div>
<div class="when-closed"> - <div>

...


<style>

.collapsed > .when-open,
:not(.collapsed) > .when-closed {
  display: none;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-model` to manage and track the UI state.

You can do something like:

```html
<b-btn v-b-toggle="'some-dynamic-id'">{{ Title }}</b-btn>
<b-collapse v-model="openState" id="some-dynamic-id">
  {{ Content }}
</b-collapse>
```

At this point you can decide to declare `openState` as `true` or `false` inside the data section or to set its value in the mounted or created lifecycle hooks, maybe based on a prop (as I did in my case).

Once the user starts clicking, the value will be synchronized with its state in the UI.

The minus / plus part would then become:

```html
<span class="fa" :class="openState ? 'fa-minus' : 'fa-plus'"></span>
```